# Active record without JOIN

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have

```
class Autosalon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :autos
end

class Auto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :autosalon
end
```

autosalon has flag active=1 and date of registration, auto has flag  active=1

How get all autos with active flag in autosalons with active flag **without JOIN**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any joins/includes, you could use a SQL `in` query:

```
Auto.where(:active => 1).where("autosalon_id in (select id from autosalons where active=1)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
active_autosalons = Autosalon.where(:active => 1)
active_autos = Autos.where(:autosalon_id => active_autosalons.map(&:id)).where(:active => 1)
```

Get the list of 'active' Autosalons first, then filter Autos by the Autosalon ids and the active column.